# Background position fixed not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

```
<td width=100% style="vertical-align:baseline;height:500px;background-color:#fff;background:url('hjadshjkwqueqejbjbqwbeg110054roads.jpg') no-repeat fixed;background-size:cover;background-color:#fff">
```

This problem is only being faced in Firefox. 
Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: I saw an answer where they were talking about searchandshare.css .I don't know what that is.

Comment: create a fiddle to show your exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found some fails in your code. Try again.

```
<td style="width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; vertical-align:baseline; height:500px; background: url('path/to/you/image.png') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;">
```

Comment: Firefox? I want the solution for firefox. And did you check the link?

Comment: yes of yourse, i have check you site with firedox and chrome. can you show me a picture where the page looks like right ?

Comment: was it because you have the page not updated properly?

Comment: Actually the browser wasn't able to render the image after scrolling and the image became distorted (probably because of my processor lol), so it became difficult for me to check whether the image remained fixed or not. Then I tried to refresh the page after scrolling a bit, and saw that the image remained fixed. :)

Comment: oh okay. But you site isn't responsive. If you minimize your browser display, the text and the menu soll broken. Good Luck

Comment: Yeah I am going to redirect the users with screen size <1000 to a mobile site. :)

Comment: Pls answer this question too: :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780144/browsers-showing-different-results-for-same-jquery-code

Comment: but is not it better just to create a responsive layout? A year ago, I even thought so and was somewhat inexperienced in css but today I can tell you that it is much easier to directly create a responsive layout. my friend has build a very easy css framework wich you can create easy responsive layouts. if you will you can use it.

Comment: Actually I have no idea about how to create a responsive layout.. :P Yeah if you friend agrees then you can provide me that framework. I would try my best to create a responsive layout. :)

Comment: Yes of course, the Framework is for free. Would you like to add me or my freind in skype because for the Framework isn't at this time a description like "how to".

Comment: Well, what's your name? and where do you live? ..you have no info on your profile page. :P

Comment: Iam live in Germany and am 16, my Skypeaccount is: Eliaspaul2