# Browsers showing different results for same Jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have tried to create iOS Safari tabs like UI for the page.

Please visit [this](http://gmdconsultants.in/gallery.html) page, *it's safe*, using Chrome, IE, and Firefox (all) (if not possible then refer the image below).

As you can see that only chrome is able to show me the Jquery results perfectly. Its still fine in Firefox as the content is visible, but in IE the matter (images) after scrolling down is not at all visible.

Please provide me a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

[image: Right click and click on "open image in new tab"]Right click and click on "open image in new tab" (and then zoom in)

THIS IS THE CODE USED FOR EVERY IMAGE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var repeataction= function() { 
var height=$(window).height(); 
var position=$("#imagett1").position(); 
var percent=position.top/height*100; 
if(position.top>-750){
$("#imagett1").height(percent*2 +550);

if(percent>50){$("#imagett1").height((100-percent)*2 +550)}; };

};
var timeOut= setInterval(repeataction, 1); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Damn that's brutal. Bind an event handler to `scroll` instead of firing that function every millisecond.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you have severely invalid HTML, but as René says that's some heavy hammering you're doing...

Comment: Then what should I do to have the same output?

Comment: How should I know? Do you have a live example we can test?

Comment: Actually I tried increasing the time upto 250ms, but then I looked as if iPhone 1 was trying to run ios 7. lol

Comment: Yeah I have linked the site in the question above. http://gmdconsultants.in/gallery.html